# How to execute code when signOut Nextjs with NextAuth?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

i'm working with **NextAuth** and i want to remove refresh token from database when user **signOut**.

any trick to do it right ?

I'm using `"next-auth": "^4.3.2"` with `"next": "12.1.5"`

Comment: QUestion needs some code and npm packages with versions you are using.

Answer (score 0):

import { signOut } from "next-auth/react";

inside component write click handler

```
const logoutHandler = () => {
    signOut();
  };
```

then use it in your button or link

```
            <Link href="/">
                <a
                  className="text-danger"
                  onClick={logoutHandler}
                >
                  Logout
                </a>
              </Link>
```